# How get sharable link of google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, permissions, sharing

I have created a google spreadsheet using web-apps-script and want to assign it a view-only access.

how can I do so I tried many different method but it does not work and keeps giving me errors.

For example:-
[image]

I want any method to share my file to other user either by getting a shareable link or adding it into a public folder.

First I tried sharing it using script but received error :-

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("allowance "+(new Date));
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssNew.getUrl());
var fileId = ss.getId();
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor("sritu@gmail.com");
```

Then I tried moving spreadsheet into public folder but nothing works and I receive error:-

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("allowance "+(new Date));
var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('0AOexqtJ8UhRxPWUyk9PVxxA');
var id = ssNew.getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
folder.addFile(file);
```

Comment: From the error message, if you manage the scopes using the manifest file (`appsscript.json`), as a test case, how about adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and trying it again?

Comment: How do I do that its just a published app. I have no clue how to do so may be I will have to ask another question for that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `How do I do that its just a published app.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I have less knowledge of script and therefore I have no idea what file or page to begin with. I guess I should close this question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: From [tag:gas-web-app] usage guideline, **Questions about web applications must include how the app is published: 1. Execute as"Me"/"User accessing the web-app". 2.Access:" Anyone"/"Anyone even anonymous"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to update your permissions:

Taking into account the error you're getting, here's what I think is happening:

- You first [deployed your web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) with a **Project version**, and authorized the web app to access user's data. **In this first version of the app, `DriveApp.getFileById` was not part of the code, so you didn't authorize the scopes required for calling this method**.
- After deploying the web app, you modified the script and added `DriveApp.getFileById`, which requires either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.
- After modifying the script you did not deploy a new version of the script (you would have been prompted to `Review Permissions` and authorize `DriveApp.getFileById`). Instead, you're probably trying to test the web app via **latest code** (URL ending in `/dev`), which doesn't necessarily require you to update your permissions.

To solve this, create a new **Project version** and review your permissions as you will be requested (or update any other settings for the web app, like **Execute the app as**, which can also prompt the authorization popup).